# How to create a 3 node HA Redpanda kafka cluster where one node only vote without storing any partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, redpanda

I have a 2 node system and cannot add a third.

I want to configure an HA Redpanda Kafka cluster which requires 3 nodes for election quorum:
https://docs.redpanda.com/current/deploy/deployment-option/self-hosted/manual/high-availability/

If a small compute device was added, think Intel NUC, Raspberry Pi, could I use this for election purposes and not for partition storage? It is important this device not be overloaded with our storage requirements and whatever computational workload accompanies this.

Is it possible to set the disk thresholds to very low figure or to disable partition storage/replication to that third device and still allow it to sync the configuration and cast votes in the election?

I think I have seen a situation where a zookeeper only node was ran to achieve this however we are using Redpanda: https://github.com/redpanda-data/redpanda/releases

Comment: I decided not to do this, and instead run a single stateful replica, and use Rancher Longhorn to distribute it's persistent volume across the two nodes. We maintain quorum on the k3s HA cluster, by using the third device as a master only with a taint to prevent workloads on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could run two broker processes on one machine, and use different directories for topic storage (ideally, you'd actually use different disks). This would be more easily achieved with Kubernetes, for example.

Even if you set a topic replication factor of two, you cannot control where those partitions would be placed into the cluster until after the fact, by reassigning partition placement.